# Why isn't my map() call returning the expected result?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with three checkboxes:

```
<form id="checklist-form" action="">
  <h1>this</h1>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-item0" required="">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="check-item0">
     One
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-item1" required="">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="check-item1">
      Two
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-item2" required="">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="check-item2">
      Three
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to get the value of each of the checkboxes so that I can store them in a cookie.

One my page, the first checkbox is checked. The other two are unchecked. I can use jQuery to see that the first box is checked:

```
$('#checklist-form input[type="checkbox"]').first().is(':checked')
// > true
```

Likewise, I can see the second element is not checked:

```
$($('#checklist-form input[type="checkbox"]')[1]).is(':checked')
// > false
```

Instead of querying each checkbox in turn, I want to use `map` to return an array. However, I'm not having much luck:

```
$('#checklist-form input[type="checkbox"]').map(function(el){ return $(el).is(':checked') }).toArray()
// > (3) [false, false, false]
```

I expect `[true, false, false]`. So what am I doing wrong? And is converting the checkbox states to an array entirely the correct approach if I want to store the form's state to a cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the first argument of `map()`, which is the *index* of the element in the collection, instead of the second argument, which is the reference to the element itself:

```js
var arr = $('#checklist-form input[type="checkbox"]').map(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).is(':checked');
}).toArray();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="checklist-form" action="">
  <h1>this</h1>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-item0" required="" checked="true">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="check-item0">
     One
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-item1" required="">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="check-item1">
      Two
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="check-item2" required="">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="check-item2">
      Three
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also note that you can get the `checked` property from the element directly and use `get()` instead of `toArray()` to improve the performance of the logic slightly:

```
var arr = $('#checklist-form input[type="checkbox"]').map(function(i, el) {
  return el.checked;
}).get();
```

Or even, as @charlietfl pointed out, you could remove the reliance on the arguments passed to the handler function and use the `this` keyword within the handler function, as it's called with the scope of the element provided:

```
var arr = $('#checklist-form input[type="checkbox"]').map(function() {
  return this.checked;
}).get();
```

Comment: Or `this.checked` and not worry about arguments